# Python version not finding PyQtGraph module

Tags: python, import, module, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I have been unable to connect Python with PyQtGraph and I can't see where the problem lies and how to solve it.

I'm using MacOS Ventura. The version of Python I'm using is 3.11.2.
I try to run a program importing pyqtgraph and get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqtgraph'
```

When doing either `pip3 install pyqtgraph` or `pip install pyqtgraph` I get the message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyqtgraph in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pyqtgraph) (1.24.2)
```

It seems ok to me, so I don't quite understand why it is not finding pyqtgraph. I saw some questions about the same issue but the solutions didn't make it for me.

Comment: You say `3.11.2` but path says `python3.10`, you likely have two versions of python installed, `3.10` have pyqtgraph installed and `3.11.2` does not

Comment: Then how can I get it right? I've tried uninstalling through pip but it always goes to that version

Comment: @bgly you should ensure that you run pip from the proper python interpreter that corresponds to the version in use.

Comment: This error has been happening for six years, at least. I have only one version of python installed. This is the only package that I use that shows this behavior, I have no idea why.